# Buttons on ASP Repeater as trigger for Update Panel?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to work out with the idea of assigning a trigger for Update Panel Dynamically.

```
<asp:Repeater ID='justAnID' runat='server'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID='justAnotherID' runat='server'/>
    <ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat='server'>
  <ContentTemplate>
     //mycontents
  <ContentTemplate>
  <triggers>
     //??
  <triggers>
</asp:repeater>
```

The point is - I can't come up any idea how to assign as trigger the buttons created by my repeater. Any idea for this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an async trigger in code behind by looping the Repeater items. This has to be done on every postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    }

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in justAnID.Items)
    {
        Button button = item.FindControl("justAnotherID") as Button;
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(button);
    }
}
```