# RowIndex attribute of templated field inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, aspxgridview

I want my templated buttons to have an update panel around it, but it messes up my rowindex attribute for the control. I tried to get the parent of the container but it says displayindex is not a property

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="IBRemove" EventName="click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="IBRemove" runat="server" RowIndex="<%#  Contanier.Parent.Displayindex %>"  OnClick="IBRemove_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Don't use `UpdatePanel` inside an `ItemTemplate`. Wrap the entire GridView in a single UpdatePanel.

Comment: That was my initial thought but the trigger control id can't find the templated control. So I decided to put it in the item template so the trigger would have access to the button

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446762/buttons-on-asp-repeater-as-trigger-for-update-panel/47454061#47454061). That shows how you can assign a trigger in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Link that VDWWD commented worked fine and it makes more sense to wrap the entire gridview in the update panel.

I was looking for this though:

```
RowIndex="<%# (DirectCast(Container, IDataItemContainer)).DisplayIndex %>"
```